# How can I turn a string into an operator?

Tags: go

Is there a way to convert a string (e.g. "+", "-", "/", "*") into their respective math operators (+, -, /, *)?

In Python you can do:

```
import operator
ops = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub} # etc.
print ops["+"](1,1) # prints 2
```

Is there a similar library or method for Go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with function values:

```
ops := map[string]func(int, int) int{
    "+": func(a, b int) int { return a + b },
    "-": func(a, b int) int { return a - b },
    "*": func(a, b int) int { return a * b },
    "/": func(a, b int) int { return a / b },
}

fmt.Println(ops["+"](4, 2))
fmt.Println(ops["-"](4, 2))
fmt.Println(ops["*"](4, 2))
fmt.Println(ops["/"](4, 2))
```

Output: [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/eJWoaayfqt)

```
6
2
8
2
```

For a nice print:

```
a, b := 4, 2
for op, fv := range ops {
    fmt.Printf("%d %s %d = %d\n", a, op, b, fv(a, b))
}
```

Output:

```
4 / 2 = 2
4 + 2 = 6
4 - 2 = 2
4 * 2 = 8
```

Comment: A difference to the Python version, which may or may not be relevant, is that in Python the types of operands and the result are not specified in advance (i.e., `ops["+"](4.5, 2)` gives `6.5`).

Answer (score 4):

There are few options but I would recommend just constructing the problem in a switch or using a `map[string]func` to provide a function which does the same. So... Either this;

```
ops := map[string]func(int, int) int{
    "+": func(a, b int) int { return a + b },
    "-": func(a, b int) int { return a - b },
    "*": func(a, b int) int { return a * b },
    "/": func(a, b int) int { return a / b },
}
```

or this;

```
func doOp(string op, lhs, rhs int) int {
     switch (op) {
          case "+":
             return lhs + rhs
           // ect
           default:
              // error cause they gave an unknown op string
     }
}
```

Which I use would probably depend on scope. The function imo is more portable. The map isn't read only so for example someone else could just hose it entirely by assigning a different method to `"+"`.

EDIT: After thinking about it the map sucks and I'd recommend against it. The function is more clear, stable, consistent, predictable, encapsulated ect.

Comment: The map makes sense IFF you need to do run-time registration of operators, but should probably still be encapsulated in a function call.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another implementation. This is give or take 3x faster than the string-based switch implementation but readability is a little less.

```
func RunOp(sign string, a, b int) int {
    s := byte(sign[0])
    switch s {
    case byte(43):
            return a+b
    case byte(45):
            return a-b
    case byte(47):
            return a/b
    case byte(42):
            return a*b
    default:
            return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `case byte(43):` as a very hard to read version of ``case `+`: ``.

Comment: Also doing `sign string` is a bit silly. There's no reason to not just do `op byte` and then do ``RunOp(`+`, 1, 2)``.

Comment: Simply placing byte literals into constants could improve readability and I mentioned my approach is a little less readable. Also, how would you go about calling the method that takes "op byte" as argument without forcing the user to do byte(sign[0])?

Comment: (D'oh, in the above of course I meant `case '+':`; single quotes versus backticks)

Comment: And what's your point? That a string-based implementation is more readable?